# Segmenting and applying a function to a single list

Tags: r, list, matrix, tidyverse

I have a list of elements and I would like to apply a function (e.g., `mean`) to each of these elements.

For example:
For the first set, I would like to get the `mean` of `1` and `1`, then `1` and '2', `1' and '3'.

Then `2` and `1`, then `2` and '2', finally `2' and '3'.

Finally, `3` and `1`, then `3` and '2', finally `3' and '3'

For the second set, I would then like to get the `mean` of `4` and `4`, then `4` and `5`, `4` and `6`

Then `5` and `4`, then `5` and `5`, `5` and `6`.

Finally `6` and `4`, then `6` and `5`, `6` and `6`.

I would like the final output to be a list of two matrices, where each matrix represents a set of three elements from `l1`. How could I go about getting this output?

```
l1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6)

l2 <- list(7,8,9,10,11,12)

Map(
    function(x, y) outer(unlist(x), unlist(y), `+`) / 2,
    split(l1, ceiling(seq_along(l1) / 3)),
    split(l2, ceiling(seq_along(l2) / 3))
)
```

Similar to the output from the code, but with only a single list, instead of two.

Comment: The example data that I used is in the object `l1`. Is that what you mean by input data?

Comment: Do you need `apply(expand.grid(l1, l1), 1, function(x) mean(unlist(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `outer` for this

```
out <- outer(l1, l1, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) mean(c(x[[1]], y[[1]]))))
```

-output

```
out
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[2,]  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0
[3,]  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5
[4,]  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0
[5,]  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5
[6,]  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5  6.0
```

---

Based on the updated code in OP's post, we can first `split` the `list` into two, loop over the `list` with `lapply` and do the `outer` as in the first code block

```
lapply(split(l1, ceiling(seq_along(l1) / 3)),
  function(subl1) outer(subl1, subl1, 
      FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) mean(c(x[[1]], y[[1]])))))
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  1.5  2.0
[2,]  1.5  2.0  2.5
[3,]  2.0  2.5  3.0

$`2`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  4.0  4.5  5.0
[2,]  4.5  5.0  5.5
[3,]  5.0  5.5  6.0
```

Comment: How would I separate the matrix to get two 3x3 matrices? Where the first set has `1 - 3` as the column and row names, and the second set has `4-6` as the column and row names?

Comment: @JohnHuang do you need the one as in the update

Comment: It's close to what I'm looking for. I edited my post, including code for how I separated the list involving two list but I'm unsure as to how I could do it for a single list. The output from my edited code is what I'm looking for, but instead of using two list I want it for one list.

Comment: what will be the dimensions for the output you are looking for

Comment: The dimensions would be 3x3 so essentially  three elements from the list per matrices